# Angular testing: Update component after asynchronous function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component I am testing and my test is failing despite printing the correct response.  The method I'm testing is the following:

```
fetchOrders(locationId = null, replace = true, infiniteScrollEvent = null) : void {
    let clientId = null;
    if (!this.queue) clientId = this.clientId;
    this.performInfiniteScroll = true
    this.locationId = locationId || ''

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.foodOrderProvider.fetchFoodOrders(clientId, this.locationId.toString(), replace).subscribe(data => {
        this.isLoading = false

        if (infiniteScrollEvent) infiniteScrollEvent.target.complete();

        if (this.foodOrderProvider.foodOrderLength() === data.total_length) {

          // I see this in the console
          console.log('shutting it down')

          this.performInfiniteScroll = false
        }
      })
    }, 10)
  }
```

Here's my test:

```
describe('FoodOrdersComponent', () => {
  let component: FoodOrdersPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FoodOrdersPage>;
  const mockFoodOrderProvider = jasmine.createSpyObj('FoodOrderProvider',
    ['fetchFoodOrders', 'foodOrderLength', 'getFoodOrders', 'foodOrderLength'],
    ['foodOrders$', 'foodOrders']
  )

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FoodOrdersPage ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: FoodOrderProvider, useValue: mockFoodOrderProvider},
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FoodOrdersPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  describe('with values', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.infiniteScroll = mockInfiniteScroll
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })

    it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('#fetchOrders', () => {
      it('should disable infinite scroll', () => {
        mockFoodOrderProvider.fetchFoodOrders.and.returnValue(of([{id: 1}]))
        mockFoodOrderProvider.foodOrderLength.and.returnValue(1)
        mockFoodOrderProvider.incompleteOrderLength = 1
        component.fetchOrders(1, true)

        // This fails
        expect(component.performInfiniteScroll).toEqual(false)

        // This logs the component with `performInfiniteScroll: false`
        console.log('xx', component)
      })
    })
  })
});
```

It seems to be something related to the asynchronous nature of the request however I've tried using `async` and `done()` with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: it is because your fetchOrders call is async by virtue of the setTimeout within. Why are you doing it like this? this seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `fakeAsync/tick` to move time in a fake manner.

Try the following:

```
// Wrap this whole callback with fakeAsync
it('should disable infinite scroll', fakeAsync(() => {
        mockFoodOrderProvider.fetchFoodOrders.and.returnValue(of([{id: 1}]))
        mockFoodOrderProvider.foodOrderLength.and.returnValue(1)
        mockFoodOrderProvider.incompleteOrderLength = 1
        component.fetchOrders(1, true)
        
        // Move 11 ms forward in a fake way so setTimeout is called
        tick(11);
        // This fails
        expect(component.performInfiniteScroll).toEqual(false)

        // This logs the component with `performInfiniteScroll: false`
        console.log('xx', component)
      }))
```